# get latitude and longitudefrom city name using HTML,js in bing map

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I need to get latitude and longitude by city name  using bing map. Here is my code.

```
 function Geocode() {
    //Create Bing Maps REST Services request to geocode the address provided by the user
    var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/"
       + "Colombo"
       + "?output=json"
       //Set the callback function
       + "&jsonp=GetLocationCoordinates"
       + "&key=Ai5r7K1Jy95BfrDbOV9PPvoBqYicNNe3Bapi7PczGda-l30CjbpHeLnK8XQmYcKl";
    //Submit the request

    MakeServiceRequest(geocodeRequest);

}

function MakeServiceRequest(request) {

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", request);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    GetLocationCoordinates();
}


function GetLocationCoordinates(geocodeResponse) {
    if(geocodeResponse==null) document.getElementById("txt").innerText = "This is null";
    if (geocodeResponse &&
           geocodeResponse.resourceSets &&
           geocodeResponse.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
           geocodeResponse.resourceSets[0].resources &&
           geocodeResponse.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) {

    setLoc(geocodeResponse.resourceSets[0].resources[0].geocodePoints.coordinates[0], geocodeResponse.resourceSets[0].resources[0].geocodePoints.coordinates[1], 10);
    }
    else {//The location could not be geocoded
        var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("The location could not be geocoded");
        md.showAsync();
    }
}
```

But in here it never called   function GetLocationCoordinates(geocodeResponse). How can I make to call it.?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are running this from the local context. Create an iframe and add the code in that resulting html file.

I've wrapped the code in a namespace. This way you can define where the function will be called rather than sticking your functions in the global namespace. Note I commented out your direct call of the function, its not needed.

Create a /pages/map/map.html, map.js, map.css (in other words, create a /pages/map and right click on it and select add new item and choose 'page' type named map)

In map.js include the following after 'use strict', or include in another javascript file. It's up to you.

```
    WinJS.Namespace.define("LocationServices", {
        GetLocationCoordinates: function (geocodeResponse) {
            if (geocodeResponse == null) document.getElementById("txt").innerText = "This is null";
            if (geocodeResponse &&
                   geocodeResponse.resourceSets &&
                   geocodeResponse.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
                   geocodeResponse.resourceSets[0].resources &&
                   geocodeResponse.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) {

                setLoc(geocodeResponse.resourceSets[0].resources[0].geocodePoints.coordinates[0], geocodeResponse.resourceSets[0].resources[0].geocodePoints.coordinates[1], 10);
            }
            else {//The location could not be geocoded
                var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("The location could not be geocoded");
                md.showAsync();
            }
        },
        Geocode: function () {
            //Create Bing Maps REST Services request to geocode the address provided by the user
            var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/"
               + "Colombo"
               + "?output=json"
               //Set the callback function
               + "&jsonp=LocationServices.GetLocationCoordinates"
               + "&key=Ai5r7K1Jy95BfrDbOV9PPvoBqYicNNe3Bapi7PczGda-l30CjbpHeLnK8XQmYcKl";
            //Submit the request

            this.MakeServiceRequest(geocodeRequest);

        },
        MakeServiceRequest: function (request) {

            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("src", request);
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            // GetLocationCoordinates();
        }
    });
```

In turn load map.html (which includes a reference to map.js and has your input id='txt')

```
<iframe src="ms-appx-web:///pages/map/map.html"></iframe>
```